Powerapps Office365Users.SearchUserV2 not showing full list of Office365Users in the active directory
On a powerapps form, I have a dropdown searching the users. I am using the following in the "Items" of the DataCardValue10
Filter(
    Office365Users.SearchUserV2(
        {SearchTerm:Trim(Self.SearchText),isSearchTermRequired:false}
        ).value,
         AccountEnabled = true, !IsBlank(JobTitle))

this shows only the users up to names beginning "I" like Ian, and I also cant search anyone after this.
Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a solution?
I have tried the following but got the exact same results
Filter(
    Office365Users.SearchUserV2(
        {SearchTerm:Trim(Self.SearchText),isSearchTermRequired:false,top:99999}
        ).value,
         AccountEnabled = true, !IsBlank(JobTitle))


Instead of SearchUserV2 use SearchUser V2 version are bit tricky and sometimes buggy too

thanks for the reply unfortunately  SearchUser still limits the list and I also seem to have issues with the filter on that version.


search user connection is not designed to show you all the users in your organization.
in order to properly search the users, you need to correctly setup fields property of your legacy combobox control in the properties window.


this worked by deleting the DataCardValue item within the DataCard and replacing it with a classic combo box connected to the sharepoint list.
